# Google maps - avoid multiple handlers on document

Tags: javascript, google-maps

My google maps every time I initialize it add ex.click handler to document.The same for `keydown, keyup.`
I've tried to remove all listeners by

```
google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(this.googleMapInstance);
```

but it didn't work.Other case,if I'm doing it right so please let open my mind.
That's how it's initialized at the beginning:

```
this.googleMapInstance = new google.maps.Map(element, options);
```

I just need to manage it manually because my users may call google map multiple times and I don't need to keep older handlers, when instance doesn't exist anymore (who really need it?)

Handler comes from:
https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js

```
rb=function(a, b)
```

Thanks for any suggestions where I'm making mistake.

Comment: Looks like calling:

google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(window);

google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(document);

do the job that I need. Thanks to myself!

Answer (score 0):

As you said in your comment:

```
google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(window);
google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(document);
```